# Difference between __blk_end_request and blk_end_request

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am wondering what is the difference between `blk_end_request` and `__blk_end_request` and how to chose one over the other?

Thanks.

Comment: __blk_end_request() must be called with queue lock held.  If you do not have the queue lock held, call blk_end_request().

Comment: @PeterL. Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__blk_end_request() must be called with queue lock held. If you do not have the queue lock held, call blk_end_request().